# Get running and queued tasks from ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, concurrency

I need to display all running tasks to the user. Every task is associated with a specific id. To execute tasks I use a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Each thread has the same name as the id. 
So I just have to get list of all running and and waiting in queue threads. And then get there names and display them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclass the executor, override `execute`, `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute` to keep an administration of the scheduled and running tasks.